# How can I use Ruby to load the HTML source code of a webpage to a string, and then parse it to get the inner HTML of the <title> tag?

Tags: html, ruby

I am attempting to grab the inner HTML of the  tag in an HTML source string using Ruby. How can I do that? I have searched and searched, how ever no solution is exactly helpful to me at this time. Thank you for the help!

Comment: What you are looking for is call a spider. Tarantula is a good one https://github.com/relevance/tarantula

Comment: [net/http](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) + [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example

hope that it helps

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Get a Nokogiri::HTML::Document for the page we’re interested in...

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/search?q=sparklemotion'))

# Do funky things with it using Nokogiri::XML::Node methods...

####
# Search for nodes by css
doc.css('h3.r a').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end

####
# Search for nodes by xpath
doc.xpath('//h3/a').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end

####
# Or mix and match.
doc.search('h3.r a.l', '//h3/a').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end
```